# Storybook. Invalid version. Must be a string. Got type "object"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

When I try to install storybook I get this. What's wrong?

```
npx storybook@latest init

 • Detecting project type. ✓
TypeError: Invalid version. Must be a string. Got type "object".

npm clean cache --force
```

Comment: Might be related to this open bug? https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/22573

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the very same issue, check out the stack trace, something along the line:

```
.npm/_npx/bc7e1e37fcb46ffc/node_modules/@storybook/cli/dist/generate.js:12:6408
```

It will help you to understand which dependency is a problem. In my case I had

```
"typescript":"*"
```

In my package.json configuration and that was a problem. Re-installed typescript:

```
yarn add -D typescript@latest
```

solved the problem